# printf + print lines (from ksh script) with same space between word in line

Tags: ksh

I have example of the follwoing lines from print command (from ksh script)

```
 first_name=raimondelita  last_name=plotanmkitus  Number_id=3574553442
 first_name=timratcel  last_name=plotiniues  Number_id=43
 first_name=tom  last_name=kot  Number_id=564
```

how to print the lines (up) like this (down) with printf

```
first_name=raimondelita  last_name=plotanmkitus  Number_id=3574553442
first_name=timratcel     last_name=plotiniues    Number_id=43
first_name=tom           last_name=kot           Number_id=564
```

THX for help
Yael

Comment: you didn't specify what programming language or environment you were referring to - people probably assume `C` when they see `printf`, but it sounds like you're talking about `ksh` ? Please add appropriate tags to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't show your code, it's hard to guess in what form you have your data and how you're handling it. However, [**jdehaan's**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203195/printf-print-lines-from-ksh-script-with-same-space-between-word-in-line/3203235#3203235) answer will work for ksh with slight modification. You will need to modify it further to suit your needs.

```
printf "first_name=%-15s last_name=%-15s Number_id=%10s\n" $first_name $last_name $Number_id
```

Answer (score 0):

use following code to align to 20 chars:

```
printf("%20s", str);
```

In your case it'll probably be more like

```
printf("first_name=%15s last_name=%15s Number_id=%10s\n",
        first_name, last_name, Number_id);
```

Comment: sorry but I need example for ksh not C 
THX

Comment: unfortunately I mostly use BASH, the Korn shell is something I cannot help with, sorry.